# when trying connecting to server.. failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: javascript, websocket

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/Index.html/ETOM/chat/sara' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + document.location.host + "/Index.html/ETOM2.0/chat/" + username);
```

Comment: are you sure you have a websocket server listening at localhost:8080?

Comment: document.location.host  =   localhost:8080

Comment: your error says: ws://localhost:8080/Index.html/ETOM ... your configuration says "ws://" + document.location.host + "/Index.html/ETOM2.0 ...

Comment: Where is 2.0 in your error message?

Comment: yes what is problem.  MY configuration is correct bcz. document.location.host = localhost:8080

Comment: ETOM2.0 is my project name

Comment: you'll need to provide some more context as to how you have setup your server, what do the server logs show, how do you know you have your server setup correctly?

Comment: But your error message says it is trying to connect to ETOM and not ETOM2.0, you sure the URL is correct?

Comment: Please try to call ws://localhost:8080/Index.html/ETOM2.0/chat/sara and tell us, if it works.
If it doesn't work, we need more information about your project. Used webserver, webserver-configuration, maybe routing information.

Comment: ETOM is my previous project vesion1 and now i am enhance the project to version2.0 and i already tried in ETOM same error occurred

Comment: ws://localhost:8080/Index.html/ETOM2.0/chat/sara not working .. @DER Alex  What information u want

Comment: @jay Please show us the code from your websocket server, that runs on localhost:8080. Please edit your question and paste your code there. And please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2020 Sept** (Express + socket Same port)

For all new comings try this :

```
//Back-End Node.js
const app = require("express")(); /*Running it right away*/
const server = require("http").Server(app);/*Use server Function and pass The app To It*/
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
const port = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
});


server.listen(port, () => {
 console.log("app listening on port 3000 in");
});


io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("user connected");
  socket.emit("message", { backend: "hey how are you?" });
  socket.on("another event", (data) => {
   console.log(data);
  });
});

//Front-End ES6
import io from "socket.io-client";
var socket = io("ws://localhost:3000", { transports: ["websocket"] });
socket.on("message", (data) => {
 console.log(data);
 socket.emit("another event", { frontend: "I am great thank you" });
});
```